# unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 1 bytes

Tags: php, laravel

on unserializing a serialized data i am getting this error

> unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 1 bytes

here is my code

```
$subcategorylisting = DB::table('subcategoryorders')->where('category_id',$category->id)->pluck('product_orderid');
$serialize_products = unserialize($subcategorylisting[0]);
$subcategorylisting = isset($subcategorylisting[0]) ? $subcategorylisting[0]:false;
if(isset($subcategorylisting)){
  $serialize_products = unserialize($subcategorylisting[0]);
  $serialize_productsS=implode(",",$serialize_products);
  $productlisting = \App\Productlisting::orderby(DB::raw('FIELD(id,'.$serialize_productsS.')'))->get();
}
```

Comment: seems like `$subcategorylisting[0]` has not serialized/incorrect serialized data. can you show us value of `var_dump($subcategorylisting[0]);`

Comment: Please show us a serialize string that is causing this error. It would appear like it is not a serialized string basically

Comment: Collection {#403 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => "a:2:{i:0;s:3:"466";i:1;s:3:"467";}"
  ]
}
here is the dd($subcategorylisting[0]);

Comment: Try: `$serialize_products = unserialize($subcategorylisting[0]->Collection->items[0]);`

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie its not working

Comment: _“`Collection {#403 ▼ #items: array:1 [▼ 0 => "a:2:{i:0;s:3:"466";i:1;s:3:"467";}" ] }` here is the dd($subcategorylisting[0]);”_ - that is the dump of a complex object, not a string value - trying to unserialize _this_ makes zero sense. You need to access the actual value(s) in the `#items` array here.